# DDR3 Routing Guidelines

Tags: pcb, altium, design, ddr3

I'm trying to design a PCB including DDR3 rams, I don't have much experience and knowledge working with DDR3. What are the most important guidelines to help ensure good signaling for the DDR3 chip? I found some information about it in forums, but maybe someone could tell more about DDR3 board design? What is the key aspects in order to design a working board?

Comment: I'm 100% I saw some videos on DDR3 routing on the youtube. Search Robert Feranec ddr3 or something on the youtube. The man is a boss and also offers well-reviewed courses for all levels of pcb design (arduino through desktop cpu level stuff). I'm actually considering getting a course, but I don't have an altium, maybe will pirate altium just for that course, because the knowledge there seems really useful according to many (my company doesn't do development for life, it's only me who develops smaller stuff, so nobody will buy altium for me)

Comment: @Ilya  Yes, i found a few Robert Feranec videos. Short and clear information about routing.